# Loggin a print statement in Azure Functions .NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: azure, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions app that I wish to have logging in both my local and Azure deployment. I want to log my print statements. I am hoping to be able to view the statements in the "log stream" in my deployment and in a window in visual studio on my local. Here is an example of my function:

```
[FunctionName("GetProjectLists")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "project-lists/{projectId}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            [AccessToken] AccessTokenResult accessTokenResult,
            int projectId)
{
    var error = AccessTokenReponse.ValidateResponse(accessTokenResult);

    if (error != null)
    {
        return error;
    }

    try
    {
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(accessTokenResult.Principal.Claims);
        var account = await _tokenCache.GetAccount(userIdentity);

        // Check if the account is null or if the user is not an admin
        if (account == null || !account.isAdmin)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"User Identity: {userIdentity.Name}, Account ID: {account.id}, Account Admin: {account.isAdmin}");
            // User is not authorized to access this resource
            return new StatusCodeResult(401); // Returns a 401 Unauthorized
        }

        // ... Do Work
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);
    }
}
```

I have added the following to my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I have opened the Output window and selected the Debug option but the print statement never gets logged.

How do I configure this so the logger prints to the console on my local and log stream in my deployment?

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using?

Comment: `Print Statements` what do you want to log?. `log.LogInformation` or Are you looking for any other logs.

Comment: Make sure your account is not null,as you have set the log message inside the if condition.